# How to make a dragon's whip even deadlier?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, weapons, dragons, natural

So, in my previous question, the two most popular weapons for a dragon were wings and the tail.

The core concept is that my slightly-larger-than-a-draft-horse dragon, who still only weighs a mere 500 kilograms, uses his tail as a whip. Dragon tails are long, but usually sleek and laterally compressed, sometimes dragons use them as rudders.

As you can see in [this video](https://youtu.be/ctaA4iFnITg?t=37), this model tail has enough power to it to shatter a jawbone.

However, this isn't enough, you can never overkill, when it comes to natural weapons (as long as the animal doesn't uses it on their kin).

Dragon bones are similar in composition to limpet teeth at the molecular level, granting them significantly more strength, albeit for only one direction. They're analogous to carbon fiber and other short-fiber composites.

Since between each other, dragons either wrestle like water monitors or compete on who can stay in the air longer, the most likely targets will be armored <s>skeptics</s> knights. The knights are almost always dismounted as dragons can startle trained horses from a distance.

**Given these, how can the dragon's tail whip be even more deadly against armored, human enemies?**

Answer (score 6):

Quills.

A part of the very tip of the tail forms quills that can be expelled at will upon a tail whip. This will would then have the velocity of the snapping tail, being supersonic, or at the very least trans sonic. It'd go through any armor like a hot knife through soft butter at those velocities. It would be comparable to a bullet from a pistol, or worse if it expels multiple quills or large one. These could also be venomous, in case just having super/trans sonic projectiles isn't quite deadly enough for you yet.

Comment: At first I imagined a lot of mini-Starlords coming out of the tail :D

Comment: @Renan If only... That'd be absolutely glorious.

Answer (score 2):

They can [explode their tails at will](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/29377/21222). That will leave a mark!

Then they can [regenerate the tail like a lizard or a salamander would](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regeneration_(biology)).

For added fun, they could have loose, spiky bones around the tail vertebra, which will act as shrapnel when the tail blows up. Those might also be loaded with a venom similar to that of the [brazilian hardon spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneutria#Danger_to_humans). Now there are two things you need to know about this spider's venom:

- It is always cited when you google for "most venomois animals" or "most potent venom". The wiki above states that while it is lethal, the animals isually doesn't deliver a lot and only ~2% of bites pose a danger. Nevertheless, your dragon may simply produce a lot of it.
- The wiki also grossly mistranslates the meaning of the spider's name in brazilian portuguese, maybe out of naivette. It's name does not mean "armed". At the very least a literal translation should be "armer" or "weaponsmith". The contextual translation is "she who gives you a boner". That's because [the bite will cause lasting erections on men](https://www.livescience.com/4429-natural-viagra-spider-bite-erection.html). It's not like viagra, which restores sexual function and allows an otherwise limp penis to go hard; if you have boy parts and get this venom in your system, you will have an erection that is painful, can last over a day, and can cause your penis to go gangrenous even if it is not the site of the bite. Of course, this will lead to all kinds of legends and myth. And since [boys will be boys](https://www.bmj.com/content/349/bmj.g7094), this will draw a lot of knights to an early grave.

Comment: Why detonate the tail? Or you meant striking with it so hard the tail actually breaks, like when Zeppeli dislocates his own shoulder for more reach, knowing he can just repair it with hamon?

Comment: @mephistoteles I mean an actual explosion, for added force.

Comment: How exactly do you want to explode a tail?

Comment: @mephistoteles check the first link, it is full of ideas from fellow worldbuilders ;)

Answer (score 2):

Scales with sharp ridges:

[image]

You can see that some of the scales on this crocodile have small ridges on them.
Now what if the scales on the side of your dragons tails are very sharp and spiky? Against unarmored targets they will be quite dangerous and used to create nasty cuts, expeically if the power of the whips isn't strong enough to break any bones.
But of course your knights are armored and the scales aren't likely wounded by the spik. Here the ridges work as lots of tiny hooks. They will hook onto a knights armor and make it easier for the dragon to throw them of their feet.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly. My first thought would be spikes on the whip. :)